# find all elements that used a specific css selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, web-developer-toolbar

Trying to do some front end design work and I needed to do some debugging/testing of my css.

I know with most browser dev tools, I can click on an elements and get a full style trace.

But what I want to do is the reverse.

I know the selector and I wish to find all elements that are associated with it (simple ctrl+f not working out)

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5):

You can surely do this in the normal Javascript console with `document.querySelectorAll`.

So if you want to find all the elements that match `body div.heading h1`, do

```
document.querySelectorAll('body div.heading h1');
```

The browser console will show the elements it has found. Most also highlight them in the page when you mouseover the listing in the console.